# Tests for object size discrimination in mammals?

Tags: vision, literature, mammals, protocol

Are there common testing protocols for establishing whether an animal (mammals especially) can distinguish the size of objects? In particular, are there procedures or is there good literature on ways to determine whether a given species can recognizes a given object as enlarged in specific settings, ideally in ways that can allow comparison across species (e.g., species A sees an object as enlarged while species B does not).